# UIScrollView, showing that there is more data by fading out text

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

Is there a way to fade text at the bottom and top when there is more data to be scrolled through in the UIScrollView?  Would I have to put something on top of the UILabel I have in the UIScrollView in order to get that effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`CAGradientLayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) on both top and bottom. You can add/remove this in the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:` based on the scroll view's `contentOffset`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ImageView as a subview for scroll view with an transparent png in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fade views in and out using Core Animation. See the [Animations](http://tinyurl.com/3kl8xqg) section of the *View Programming Guide for iOS* for an idea of what you can easily animate. There's even an example (Listing 4-1) of animating the alpha property.

Comment: Do you happen to know if you can only choose a portion of your view to do that on?  Since my UIScrollView is 300,400, I would only want to decrease the alpha for the top and bottom of the UIScrollView.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were looking for -- after rereading, it sounds like you want something that looks like UIPickerView's scrolling list. Overlaying a gradient as @Deepak suggests is the right way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing Deepak's suggestion in Swift.

I think it would be like this,

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! ///< the scrolling text
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
var yEnd : CGFloat = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    yEnd = CGFloat(textView.bounds.height) / CGFloat(textView.contentSize.height)
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textView.contentSize.width, height: textView.contentSize.height)
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.2, 0.8, 1]
    gradientLayer.opaque = false
    gradientLayer.opacity = 1
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: yEnd)
    scrollOrigin = textView.bounds.origin.y
    // scroll to the top of the text. It will trigger scrollViewDidScroll
    textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), animated: false)
    textView.layer.mask = gradientLayer
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // move the CALayer as we scroll, otherwise the fade will be scrolled away
    let lineHeight : CGFloat = 20
    let yOffset = CGFloat(scrollView.contentOffset.y) / CGFloat(scrollView.bounds.height)
    let yBottom = lineHeight - (textView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y - scrollView.bounds.height)
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: yOffset * yEnd)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: (1 + yOffset) * yEnd)
    // change the alpha on top to fully visible on start of text
    let alphaTop = yOffset > 0 ? yOffset < 0.2 ? 5 * (0.2 - yOffset) : 0 : 1
    let alphaBottom = yBottom > 0 ? yBottom / lineHeight : 0
    gradientLayer.colors = [
        UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: alphaTop).CGColor,
        UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor,
        UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor,
        UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: alphaBottom).CGColor
    ]
}

}
```

The problem with this is that I see some delay in the gradient updates, so it's not completely smooth.