# Changing the alpha inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uilabel, alpha

I was trying to achieve the effect of having my text fade in and out to show there is more data in the UIScrollView in this post: [UIScrollView, showing that there is more data by fading out text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345476/uiscrollview-showing-that-there-is-more-data-by-fading-out-text)

I could not get the CAGradientLayer to look right since my background isn't a simple black and white background and I couldn't get it to match and make it look like the text is fading.  So I thought I'd try setting the alpha property inside the UIScrollView, or the UILabel's alpha inside the UIScrollView.  However, it changes all the text's alpha.  Is there a way to do it for only a portion of the text, or a portion of the scrollView?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, at least two of which are reasonably easy:

1. Create a copy of your background with "feathered" edges. Stick this in a view on top of the scroll view.
2. Set `view.layer.maskLayer` on an appropriate view (a UIView containing the scroll view should work) to something suitable (e.g. a CALayer with contents/contentsScale/contentsCenter set appropriately). More of a pain, since CALayer does not autosize itself (so your wrapper view will have to do the necessary things in -setFrame:/-setBounds:/-layoutSubviews). You'll need to `#include <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>`.

Comment: How do you copy the background with "feathered" edges?  I'm not sure what you mean in the (2) one.  Set it to something suitable?  Thanks.